# Issue with routing in ASP.NET MVC route.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am having an issue with my routeConfig file. It is my understanding that when it processes it goes through and finds a match and should not care of the order.

Correct me if I am wrong. I have a working project, it has been a while since i developed it, and i have all my custom routes in the routeConfig file. then at the very end of it I left the default route. This was to catch any links that did not follow a custom route.

I did remove this at one point and it broke the site. So I left it at the end. Now in this new project I have done the same thing. For some reason it seems to be ignoring routes. So specifically I have an Explorer that shows a list of folders in a directory it has a custom route to get the contents of the main folder and then each folder listed is select-able to its content.

I have an action to delete a folder and when I have tried to "Delete" I am getting a page that says that the directory doesn't exist. If I put the default route on top it works. Thus ignoring the custom route. This also breaks the explorer from working as well. So when default route is on top it ignores what is below it. I really do not know what I am missing, however maybe someone else can see something I don't.

Here is my routeConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Explorer",
        url: "Explorer/{*path}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Explorer",
                        action = "Index",
                        path = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DeleteFolders",
        url:  "Explorer/DeleteTreeItem/{*path}",
           new { controller = "Explorer", action = "DeleteTreeItem", path = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

I have tried leaving the "path = UrlParameter.Optional" out as well and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Haven't looked at the code yet, but routing in asp.net mvc is 100% dependent on the order that you add them to the dictionary. Once mvc finds a route that matches the incoming request, it will stop searching. It doesn't do a best match, just the first that satisfies the constraints.

Comment: @Kolichikov Thanks for clearing that up for me. I placed the delete route before the Explorer route and it seems to be working now. I suppose that it is because the two routes are similar, however it did not break my links to the folder tree by having it under the delete. Like it did visa versa...

Comment: Glad it worked! It is probably trying to pick up the DeleteTreeItem as the entry into the path variable, optional or not (so in your case, it's treating Explorer/DeleteTreeItem as Explorer, path=DeleteTreeItem. Switching the routes doesn't break anything that is just Explorer/{*path} (unless {*path} will equal DeleteTreeItem, which you should avoid).